# uvc_camera: pixel format unavailable with USBTV007 EasyCAP

Tags: ros, usb-cam, camera, uvc-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I'm using a USBTV007 EasyCap (ID 1b71:3002 by lsusb) to capture wireless video. The system can already see it in /dev/ as video0 and I can use VLC media player to display the video on the screen and even record the video to a file. However, when I tried using uvc_camera to access the camera, this appeared:

```
pixfmt 0 = 'YUYV' desc = '16 bpp YUY2, 4:2:2, packed'
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
what():  pixel format unavailable
```

It cannot start, and I cannot get the video to ROS.

I also tried with uvc_cam and usb_cam, and they don't work too.

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 with Groovy. Also the kernel is updated to 3.11 (I found [here](http://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/Easycap#USBTV007_EasyCAP) that from 3.11, this model is supported; before the update the device was not seen as a video device.)

Any solutions or suggestions are appreciated.

Thank you,
Veerachart

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194119/uvc_camera:-pixel-format-unavailable-with-usbtv007-easycap/) by [Veerachart](https://answers.ros.org/users/5334/veerachart/) on ROS Answers with karma: 86 on 2014-10-03

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2014-10-12**:
Have you tried http://wiki.ros.org/libuvc_camera ?

**Comment by [Veerachart](https://answers.ros.org/users/5334/veerachart/) on 2014-10-13**:
Thanks for the suggestion. I'll try this as soon as I have the chance and update the result.

**Comment by [Veerachart](https://answers.ros.org/users/5334/veerachart/) on 2014-10-15**:
That does not work, with the same error of pixel format unavailable.

```
v4l2-ctl --list-formats-ext
```

gives

```
ioctl: VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT
Index       : 0
Type        : Video Capture
Pixel Format: 'YUYV'
Name        : 16 bpp YUY2, 4:2:2, packed
```

http://www.ideasonboard.org/uvc/ not supported?

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2014-10-17**:
You can try to use something like guvcview to test UVC-compatibility. If it doesn't work there, it's not going to work with the UVC driver.

**Comment by [Veerachart](https://answers.ros.org/users/5334/veerachart/) on 2014-10-18**:
If it's not compatible to UVC, is there any other driver that I can try?

**Comment by [Veerachart](https://answers.ros.org/users/5334/veerachart/) on 2014-10-20**:
@Eric Perko I tried and guvcview cannot start with the capture device attached, so it is not compatible with UVC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Now I already got it working by using gscam package, with this launch file from the v4l example in the package, removing the framerate option:

```
<launch>
    <!-- This launchfile should bring up a node that broadcasts a ros image
    transport on /webcam/image_raw -->
    <arg name="DEVICE" default="/dev/video0"/>
    <!-- The GStreamer framerate needs to be an integral fraction -->
    <arg name="FPS" default="30/1"/>
    <arg name="PUBLISH_FRAME" default="false"/>
    <node ns="v4l" name="gscam_driver_v4l" pkg="gscam" type="gscam" output="screen">
        <param name="camera_name" value="default"/>
        <param name="camera_info_url" value="package://gscam/examples/uncalibrated_parameters.ini"/>
        <param name="gscam_config" value="v4l2src device=$(arg DEVICE) ! video/x-raw-rgb! ffmpegcolorspace"/>
        <param name="frame_id" value="/v4l_frame"/>
        <param name="sync_sink" value="true"/>
    </node>
    <node if="$(arg PUBLISH_FRAME)" name="v4l_transform" pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" args="1 2 3 0 -3.141 0 /world /v4l_frame 10"/>
</launch>
```

With this, topic /v4l/camera/image_raw is available for further use.

Thanks for suggestions @Eric Perko.

---

Originally posted by [Veerachart](https://answers.ros.org/users/5334/veerachart/) with karma: 86 on 2014-10-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1